# ASP.NET Core StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I make a post request to the api and my middleware seems to be working but when it gets to *return OK* the program crashes and gives this error
**Status Code cannot be set because the response has already started**

Program.cs

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<MyShortCircuitMiddleware>();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

bool recreateDatabase = builder.Configuration.GetValue("recreateDatabase", false);
using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDatabaseContext>();
if (recreateDatabase)
{
    await dbContext.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
    await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();

}
await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();

DomainValidator.GetInstance().Initialize(builder.Configuration);

app.Run();
```

MyExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);

           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical("[Exp][API] Something went wrong: {}", ex);
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
        

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { 
            title = "Something went wrong!",
            status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            errorCode =(int)ErrorCode.ServerFault
        });

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have another middleware registered before you register your exception handling middleware which already processes the response?

Comment: Have you `awaited` all your `async Task`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved and the point was that I was calling _next() incorrectly in a part of the code, which caused the previous request to not reach the response stage, and the next request was waiting for a response.

Answer (score 1):

> I make a post request to the api and my middleware seems to be working
> but when it gets to return OK the program crashes and gives this error
> Status Code cannot be set because the response has already started.

Well, the exception you are getting it pretty obvious and it's not because of your `app.UseMiddleware<MyExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();` middleware but for the later one which is `app.UseMiddleware<MyShortCircuitMiddleware>();`. As you might know, while you have written `await _next(httpContext);` within your current middleware it won't execute any more and control would pass to your next request delegate which is `app.UseMiddleware<MyShortCircuitMiddleware>();`

And if you have written any response there soon you would encounter the exception because we cannot write response twice within a single httpcontext this causing your error in your scenario as you can see below:

**Issue Reproduced:**

[image]

**Note:** Once you have written to the Response/stream the other middleware won't be able to write again within the same context. You have to replace the Response/stream if you want to write and pass one down the pipeline. I would highly recommend you to [have a look our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-code-analysis).

**Solution:**

1. Do not write response twice within same context:

Your issue can be resolved either way. If you need to write the response on your MyShortCircuitMiddleware you should end it there and not call the next in the pipeline or do not get back to MyExceptionHandlerMiddleware.

2. Check If The Response Already Started:

You can set conditionals to check if the response has started  written already. For instance, [HasStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.hasstarted?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is a useful hint to indicate if headers have been sent or the body has been written to. you can do something:

```
If(!context.Response.HasStarted)
 {
   //... Do something here
 }
```

But do not try to write response in both middlware together. I hope it would provide you the transparent background why the error encountered.

**Output:**

As you can see, I haven't write any response from MyShortCircuitMiddleware. Thus, MyExceptionHandlerMiddleware is working as expected without any issue.

[image]

In addition, please be aware of following invocation:

[image]

**Note:** You can get more details here in this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-webapplication).

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that, you are trying to set the status code after the response body is written.

to resolve this, try setting the status code before anything is written.

In your case in the HandleExceptionAsync method try setting the status code on start of the function.

```
 private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { 
        title = "Something went wrong!",
        status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
        errorCode = (int)ErrorCode.ServerFault
    });

    await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
}
```